# Adding mysqldump parameters in automysql

Tags: mysql, database-backup, mysqldump

Please excuse any formatting or grammatical errors.

I am currently using automysqlbackup to take local backups of my mySQL database. I recently started to having problems that is connected to that automysqlbackup (or in fact mysqldump) does lock the tables before dumping.

I have not access to any mySQL user or the root user, only the /etc/mysql/debian.cnf.

I would need to add the parameter "--lock-tables=false" so automysqlbackup does'nt lock the tables. I am aware of the risks that follows.

Comment: Read also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104612/run-mysqldump-without-locking-tables

Comment: @lg. It seems that you did not read the question. This question is about automysqlbackup that uses mysqldump - not mysqldump itself

Comment: I read your question. I only suggested you to read that post because the option to include changes for myisam and innodb engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added this option on /etc/default/automysqlbackup

## OPTIONS

OPT="$OPT --lock-tables=false"

Comment: Yes, that is the correct solution!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this myself.

Line 431 in /usr/sbin/automysqlbackup contain the "command", editing that line solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

"OPT="$OPT --lock-tables=false""

It will not work

/usr/sbin/automysqlbackup initiate OPT variable, so it will not pass from /etc/default/automysqlbackup